# Record function argument as union type is not assignable to its union values

Tags: typescript

The goal is to declare a `Record` type definition for a mapper in order to restrict the keys and function values.
The arguments of those functions have different behaviors, thus are defined using a union type.

`PushNotificationPayloadVideoComment` is part of `PushNotificationPayload` union type, but the TS compiler detects that it's not assignable to its union

[image]

TypeScript version: 4.3.2

[Click here for the full code snippet on TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgrgZwBYDkD2wCWAzTBjAQyzQDsYCQAbNAgEwDVNaI0AZTAa2gF4oBvAFBQohYBADmaAE4gAXFADkANyYsA+pU4QFAbiFQVzNGqbyEwKZhLi9AXz2hIsRKgw58RTKXJUaDVWgAwmgAtiEQJMBQvILCohLScoqG6nih4ZG6+inGplDmltZ6cekRwCa0ZhZWNgL2Ao7Q8MjoWLiiXmQU1HTBYWXsXNH8+vGSMvIKaf2RGlpZwjkVVYW1JTPleQU1dg7gTS6t7h3e3X4AsgRSXFjWw7EiRAkTiiFXNzVZ9Y3OLW7tnlOvl6pUiACUIGBKCB7qMnuMklNQeUpJDoV89A19r9XG0PMQusDaNF9AAfHFHAEEnw9fxGQYQMkU-74zo0vyMIx9DLAJnNXHHQGE2ncgZaPmHFknYV+UXgtEgCV-PHS9l0S7XCC3WpYpyXMCQKTDCFpKS0AA8+n5lNZQNpAG0pvDEgoALoAGn0AAowGc6PI4CQOCQ0AB3EgASmiAD4DGgmAJo3o0iRzFA3mAUAQVOIhQAhEA26WBZ0vfWG2GLAJqaY8+RevgGatMKC2eTWqVCtV0lhy4BR7ixh7CEjZzC5sQAFTQnJYDabRgqrYjxVbnvWPLmXHrjaWLbbzJVXb9tD7DIHQ-0I7HE4g09naHne+JthX+ls64X6k026gXovIzCNeOZChC2AAHR4HAUiopEAD84GjiBYhegoMBSGguCUNo7qAUBwgIHgqIRJM6GYZg2EKJ++G+lIBAhAg8jDvh+QQNheBiLQk4EAARvIACM1FAR+V7LquIn2EAA)

Comment: The error appears in the official playground.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I wasn't able to see it, but thanks for noticing it - I've just edited the question :)

Comment: The error is appearing when the TS complier Option *strictFunctionTypes* is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unknown` means the function assigned should be capable to handle any parameter type, and you are using functions that can only handle a specific type.

You could use a custom mapped type to map each callback to the appropriate parameter type:

```
type Mapper = {
  [P in PushNotificationPayload as P['category']]?: (payload: P) => void
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=31&pln=19&pc=29#code/C4TwDgpgBACgrgZwBYDkD2wCWAzTBjAQyzQDsYCQAbNAgEwDVNaI0AZTAa2gF4oBvAFBQohYBADmaAE4gAXFADkANyYsA+pU4QFAbiFQVzNGqbyEwKZhLi9AXz2hIsRKgw58RTKXJUaDVWgAwmgAtiEQJMBQvILCohLScoqG6nih4ZG6+inGplDmltZ6cekRwCa0ZhZWNgL2Ao7Q8MjoWLiiXmQU1HTBYWXsXNH8+vGSMvIKaf2RGlpZwjkVVYW1JTPleQU1dg7gTS6t7h3e3X4AsgRSXFjWw7EiRAkTiiFXNzVZ9Y3OLW7tnlOvl6pUiACUIGBKCB7qMnuMklNQeUpJDoV89A19r9XG0PMQusDaNF9AAfHFHAEEnw9fxGQYQMkU-74zo0vyMIx9DLAJnNXHHQGE2ncgZaPmHFknYV+UXgtEgCV-PHS9l0S7XCC3WpYpyXMCQKSw4QAbRgUCszJVQrVxIICFgJqm8MSCgAum6APzyAAUYDOdHkMAAlNEAHwGNBMOoCARpEjmKBvMAoAgqcRCgBCIEprNIgRdL31huNBgCammPN9fDLRgqUFsoe4EYewn0tgANKNkXMuNXa+omA2my39G3hJ3suXNH2oD6RyNhOOG137EA)